# Dagger 2.0 Constructor injection and Singleton

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2

is it possible to use Dagger 2.0 Constructor injection and singleton at one time.
I don't find the answer in the documentation.

Example:

```
@Singleton
public class MyClass {
   private final OtherClass member;

   @Inject
   public MyClass(OtherClass member){
        this.member = member;
   }
 }
```

Constructor injection does work for sure. But is it guaranteed that MyClass is created as a singleton if I write @Singleton on the class?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

Since Dagger 2 generates the source code for you, it is easy to inspect what is happening. For example, when using the following module in combination with your `MyClass`:

```java
@Component
@Singleton
public interface MyComponent {
  MyClass myClass();
}
```

The following implementation is generated:

```java
@Generated("dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor")
public final class DaggerMyComponent implements MyComponent {
  private Provider<MyClass> myClassProvider;

  private DaggerMyComponent(Builder builder) {  
    assert builder != null;
    initialize(builder);
  }

  public static Builder builder() {  
    return new Builder();
  }

  public static MyComponent create() {  
    return builder().build();
  }

  private void initialize(final Builder builder) {  
    this.myClassProvider = ScopedProvider.create(MyClass_Factory.create(OtherClass_Factory.create()));
  }

  @Override
  public MyClass myClass() {  
    return myClassProvider.get();
  }

  public static final class Builder {
    private Builder() {  
    }

    public MyComponent build() {  
      return new DaggerMyComponent(this);
    }
  }
}
```

In `initialize(Builder)`, you can see that a `ScopedProvider` is used as a `Provider` for `MyClass`. When calling the `myClass()` method, the `ScopedProvider`'s `get()` method is called, which is implemented as a singleton:

```java
public T get() {
  // double-check idiom from EJ2: Item 71
  Object result = instance;
  if (result == UNINITIALIZED) {
    synchronized (this) {
      result = instance;
      if (result == UNINITIALIZED) {
        instance = result = factory.get();
      }
    }
  }
  return (T) result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I only looked into the generated code of my subcomponent. But in the main component I can find the ScopedProvider